# Small letter e with double grave

Tags: accents

can anyone tell me how to get a small letter e with a double grave on it in latex?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of word with this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language uses this character, and in which word?

Comment: @Rightleg From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_grave_accent): “The double grave accent is a diacritic used in scholarly discussions of the Serbo-Croatian and sometimes Slovene languages. It is also used in the International Phonetic Alphabet.”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The accent is available in standard `pdflatex` with `tipa`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}

\begin{document}

\textdoublegrave{e}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use direct input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0205}{\textdoublegrave{e}}

\begin{document}

\textdoublegrave{e} ȅ

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX this is very easy:

```
% Use either xelatex or lualatex to compile this example
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
ȅ
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you insert it using keyboard? Which layout do you have?

Comment: @Sigur I've used `emacs` with C-x 8 Enter 205 Enter (→ [How to type a Unicode character by its number in Emacs?](https://superuser.com/questions/394405/how-to-type-a-unicode-character-by-its-number-in-emacs)). But you can also use copy&paste from any unicode character table. For other character like `ë` I use the compose key.

Comment: Someday I'll learn how to use Emacs.

Comment: is it possible anyhow to get it in a pdflatex ?

Comment: @amarko10, see egreg's answer.

Comment: @amarko10 Is there a reason not to use `xelatex` or `lualatex`?